# Lua Loop - Any Advice?

Tags: lua

Could anyone give me some advice on this code? I cant make it so that when the user ends the calculation the process repeats if he types in "y". could anyone help ?

```
if choice == "2" then
    repeat os.execute( "cls" )
    print "How many numbers?"
    amountNo = io.read "*n"
end
if amountNo <= 2 then
    print "You can't have less than 2 numbers."
elseif amountNo >= 14 then
    print "Can't calculate more than 14 numbers."
else
    local sum = 0
    for i = 1, amountNo do
        print( ('Enter number %s'):format(i) )
        local nmb = io.read '*n'
        sum = sum + nmb / amountNo
    end
    print( (' The sum is: %s'):format(sum) )
    print(" Do you want to repeat the calculation? Y/N ?")
    yesno = io.read()
    yesno_input = true or false
    if yesno == "y" or "Y" or "yes" or "Yes" then yesno = true 
    if yesno == "n" or "N" or "no" or "No" then yesno = false
    until yesno==false

end
```

end
endre

Comment: oh god that indentation.

Comment: After fixing the indentation I can in fact see that this code is borked and in desperate need of a `while`/`repeat` loop at the end.

Comment: What does `yesno_input = true or false` do?

Comment: You can't have an `if` block start outside a `repeat` and end inside it, is this really the code you run? I think that first "end" must be spurious (not in your actual code).

Comment: Please do keep using StackOverflow as a learning resource. However, you should also include the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/contents.html#contents) and [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) in your learning. This question is best answered by reading those.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the whole process, the whole process has to be put in the loop, obviously:

```
repeat
  -- do stuff

  doAgain = io.read()
until doAgain:lower():sub(1,1) == "n"
```

I've replaced your checks with something simpler; `:lower()` converts user answer to lowercase and `:sub(1,1)` extracts first character from it. If you think it's too convoluted, pack it in a function.

```
function isNegativeResponse(response) 
   return response:lower():sub(1,1) == "n"
end

repeat
  -- stuff
until isNegativeResponse(io.read())
```

This looks rather natural, doesn't it? *Repeat code (stuff) inside until the user produces negative response.*

Comment: Ive got the repeat , you just couldnt see it because it was on the fight , I get an error that Repeat isnt closed but the until is placed right underneath and at the end of the code.

Comment: @user3654336 most probably you misplaced something because of your indentation.